# Using private key to sign a JWT token

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, jwt

I'm trying to load a private key to sign a JWT token. I got following code and failed with exceptions:

```cs
string key =@"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCTLOQaZ3D0ayC1BSW4LCs3gYmu
eYiWDGRT491PJt/4
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha512);

var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha512);

var header = new JwtHeader(signingCredentials);
var t = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
int iat = (int)t.TotalSeconds;
var payload = new JwtPayload
{
   { "iss", "1234-5678-9012-1221-11111"},
   { "iat", iat },
   { "exp", iat + 900},
   { "sub", "aaaaaaaaaaa" }
};

var secToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);
var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(secToken);
```

===============Answer===============================

Just for anyone facing the same problem, here is the solution. You need read the post down the bottom to get it work:

http://www.donaldsbaconbytes.com/2016/08/create-jwt-with-a-private-rsa-key/

Comment: Please provide the exception message too.

Comment: the exception does not make sense. I think I used wrong security format. What I want to achieve is that I want to use 'RS512' to encode JWT token from a private key. 
So, I have to get how to get security key object from the key value.

Comment: I edited your question. You use the key to SIGN a token, not to encode. The token is base64url encoded, but that has nothing to do with a key. The key is for signing.

Comment: thanks. I figured it out. so will post a solution here

Comment: Any luck on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with below line

```
var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha512);
```

you are trying to use symmetric key with asymmetric algorithm (RSA algorithm).

You can look for other symmetric algorithm to generate `signingCredentials` something like below

```
var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to use 'RS512' format. I am still in trouble of getting the correct SecurityKey object from a private key. Do you have any ideas? thanks.

Comment: If you need to use RSA then you can use following
`var  rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);`
`var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new RsaSecurityKey(rsa), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha512);`